# Cloudinary Nodejs Image Upload Setup Issue

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images directly from the browser to Cloudinary, but I'm having trying with the configurations. I'm following this [tutorial](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_upload) 
and I'm stuck on the step where I need to include this:

```
var cloudinary_cors = "https://" + request.headers.host + "/cloudinary_cors.html";
```

I'm getting an error saying "request is not defined". The template page does render, but the input field does nothing. I also have the "cloudinary_cors.html" file in my static directory and I'm using Pug as my template engine. Here is my template page thus far:

```
//upload.pug
extends layout

block content
  script(type='text/javascript', src='jquery.min.js')
  script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/jquery.ui.widget.js')
  script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js')
  script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/jquery.fileupload.js')
  script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/jquery.cloudinary.js')

  cloudinary.cloudinary_js_config()

  script.
    $(function() {
      if($.fn.cloudinary_fileupload !== undefined) {
        $("input.cloudinary-fileupload[type=file]").cloudinary_fileupload();
      }
    });

    var cloudinary_cors = "http://" + request.headers.host + "/cloudinary_cors.html";
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.image_upload_tag('image_id', {callback: cloudinary_cors});

 form(action='/create', method='post')
  .field
   label Image ID
   input(name='image_id')
  button.ui.primary.button(type='submit') Post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to Cloudinary sample project on Github - https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/tree/master/samples/photo_album

And to this part in specific - 
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/samples/photo_album/views/photos/add_direct.ejs